# What does it mean "is four times a prime"?

Tags: prime-numbers, terminology

In the paper "[Some strange primes](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43671321)" prove the following:

Let $p > 3$ a prime number such that $p - a^2$ is four times a prime for any positive odd integer a such that $a^2\leq p$. Then there are only six prime numbers with the property asserted in the state ment of the theorem: $5,13,29,53, 173, 293$.

I do not understand very well what the result refers to, what does it mean "is four times a prime"?

Comment: $4q$ for some prime $q$

Comment: $13$ doesn’t have that property because $13-9=4$ is not $4q$ for a prime $q$.  The other numbers all have the same issue.

Comment: They must be making an exception for $1$.  @RobertShore

Comment: it is true, 1 is considered prime

Comment: The paper explicitly says it does in the abstract. But note that in general $1$ is not considered prime, for good reason. If I were the author I might have said "noncomposite" and clarified that to mean $1$ or prime.

Comment: The author should have used "$1$ or prime". Instead of considering $1$ to be a prime it should be handled as an extra case.

Comment: Also, the "any" in the text should be replaced by "every" because it is apparently required that we have the desired form for every $a$ with $a^2<p$ and not just for some such $a$.

Answer (score 1):

For instance,  $29-1^2=28=4\cdot \color {blue}{7}\,,29-3^2=20=4\cdot \color {blue}{5},\,29-5^2=4=4\cdot \color{blue}{1}$.

So $29$ satisfies the hypothesis.

$1$ must be included as a prime for this to work.   Usually,  it's not considered a prime.  But it isn't composite either.  In the link it says that they are considering $1$ to be a prime.